# How to write DELETE Statement with Inner Query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below query works fine in Oracle DB.
The same query fails in Postgres DB, but the inner query works fine in Postgres DB.

```
DELETE FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.RESORT, A.RESV_NAME_ID ORDER BY ACTION_ID DESC) RNK
FROM STAGE_DETAILS A ) B 
WHERE B.RNK>1;
```

I am getting syntax error for this.

> Error :-
> *[Code: 0, SQL State: 42601]  ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 13  [Script position: 3109 - 3110]*

How to fix this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following syntax

```
DELETE FROM STAGE_DETAILS A
USING (SELECT ACTION_ID,RESV_NAME_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RESORT, RESV_NAME_ID ORDER BY ACTION_ID DESC) RNK
     FROM STAGE_DETAILS) B
WHERE B.RNK>1 AND B.ACTION_ID = A.ACTION_ID AND B.RESV_NAME_ID = A.RESV_NAME_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks.It works and takes around 1 sec for table containing 15000 records.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete from a subquery in Postgres.  This should do what you want:

```
DELETE FROM STAGE_DETAILS SD
    WHERE ACTION_ID < (SELECT MAX(SD2.ACTION_ID)
                       FROM STAGE_DETAILS SD2
                       WHERE SD2.RESORT = SD.RESORT AND
                             SD2.RESV_NAME_ID = SD.RESV_NAME_ID
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks,It works but takes little more time ... around 20 secs for the table containing 15000 records.